# Unable to call startService (intent) function. Intent is null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent

I have add a background music in my app.I have three activities so I want to design a music controller class which is controlled by the three activities. But when I create an object of serviceIntent in MainActivtiy and passed to the  MusicController class, the serviceIntent can not be started and the error is null pointer exception. Does anyone how to figure out this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Logcat**:

`04-13 22:30:15.189: D/AndroidRuntime(9581): Shutting down VM
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581): Process: com.example.funwithmath, PID: 9581
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.funwithmath/com.example.funwithmath.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:516)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at com.example.funwithmath.util.MusicController.startMusic(MusicController.java:25)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at com.example.funwithmath.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-13 22:30:15.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9581):     ... 10 more`

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button sound;
private Intent serviceIntent;
private MusicController musiControl;
private boolean musicPlayStatus = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    sound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundopen);
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MusicServer.class);


    //Control Background Music
    musiControl = new MusicController (serviceIntent);
    musiControl.startMusic();
```

**MusicController.java**

```
public class MusicController extends Activity {

private boolean musicPlayStatus = true;
private Intent serviceIntent;

public MusicController(Intent serviceIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.serviceIntent = serviceIntent;

}

public void startMusic() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Start Music

    startService(serviceIntent);
    musicPlayStatus = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line tells you what you need to know

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Basically there is no context in your MusicController class. The class needs to know where to start the service. We can fix this by passing in the mainActivity's Context.

```
public class MusicController extends Activity {

private boolean musicPlayStatus = true;
private Intent serviceIntent;
private Context context;

public MusicController(Context c, Intent serviceIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context = c;
    this.serviceIntent = serviceIntent;

}

public void startMusic() {

    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    musicPlayStatus = true;

}
```

Comment: Thank Max. That can help me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the object using **new**

**MusicController.java**

```
public class MusicController extends Activity {

private boolean musicPlayStatus = true;
private Intent serviceIntent;

public MusicController(Intent serviceIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.serviceIntent = serviceIntent;

}

public void startMusic() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Start Music
serviceIntent= new Intent(MusicController.this, YourService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    musicPlayStatus = true;

}
```

Here i can show you easy way to start and stop Services

For start service

```
startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

For stop service

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

**Note:-** Don't forget to add service in your AndroidManifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MainService" />
```

Comment: The OP is setting the `serviceIntent` in `MusicController`'s constructor. Setting it to a new `Intent` will just replace that with an `Intent` with no target class. This isn't what's causing the current Exception, anyway.

Comment: This still won't fix the current problem. It's still going to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yep. Look at the OP's stack trace. `Attempt to invoke virtual method '...Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`.

Comment: Try this Intent(getBaseContext(), RasPiDomBackground.class) insted of Intent(MusicController.this, YourService.class)

Comment: NPE on `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109101/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-mike-m).

Comment: Hi Arpit, thank you for your help and suggestions. I have rewrite the constructor in the subclass： public MusicController(Activity activity) And new an intent： serviceIntent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), MusicServer.class); but it still said NPE. I don't know why the intent object will be vanished after I use startService method.

Comment: Hi Mike, do you have any idea or suggestion to solve this problem?